# Prove $\sin(45^°) + \sin(15^°) = \sin(75^°)$

Tags: trigonometry

I rewrote the statement as 
$$
\sin(30^° + 15^°) + \sin(15^°) = \cos(15^°). 
$$
Then I got 
$$
(\sqrt{3}-2) \sin(15^°) = \cos(15^°).
$$

Comment: Always specify degrees or radians in the argument. Note the answer by TZakrevskiy is specific with degrees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\sin(45^{°}) + \sin(15^{°}) & = 2 \sin\left(\dfrac{45^{°}+15^{°}}2\right) \cos\left(\dfrac{45^{°}-15^{°}}2\right) = 2 \sin(30^{°})\cos(15^{°})\\
& = 2 \cdot \dfrac12 \cdot \sin(90^{°}-15^{°}) = \sin(75^{°})
\end{align}

Comment: @user233631, http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html

Answer (score 10):

$$\sin 75^° - \sin 15^°  = 2\sin\left(\frac{75^°-15^°}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{75^°+15^°}{2}\right) = 2 \sin 30^° \cos 45^° $$$$= \cos 45 ^°=\sin 45^°.$$